# how to upload file from multer to another API

Tags: node.js

I have 2 separate NodeJS APIs that uses multer to save a file.
I am able to receive the file in 1st API look like below:

```
{ fieldname: 'imageCdn',
  originalname: 'hello.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer:  <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 07 07 06 08 0a 10 0a 0a 09 09 0a 14 0e 0f 0c ... >
}
```

Now I wanna to send this data to 2nd API as below:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
service.saveImage = async (fileData) => {
  try {
    let payload = new FormData()
    payload.append('imageFile', fileData[0]);
   
    const data = await axios.post(`${app.Config.ApiUrl}/image/addImage`, payload, {headers: payload.getHeaders()});
    console.log('list:', data)

  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err)
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

> Error:  `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving that error because `fileData` is undefined when that line is executed. Without the rest of your code I can't identify the exact cause. When passing information from one API to another, the best approach would be to use [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). That way you don't need to wait for all the data to have arrived at your app before you send it off to the destination.